# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I'm new in python.. I'm trying to open a website in which you can fetch some data after filling the required form. I want to download a table after giving the particular date.
I wrote the following code but i get an error.please help...

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

URL = 'http://31.24.237.137:4100/TS/uindex.php?ct=dailyReport&act=searchCountByDay'
values = {'mehvarID': '36',
          'seperatedBy': 'all',
          'in_date': '1396/5/1'
         }
response = requests.post(URL, data=values)
data = json.loads(response.content)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
```

and here is the error I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "webscrab.py", line 11, in

data = json.loads(response.content)

raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0

Comment: are you sure that `response.content` isn't empty? why don't you print it before converting it?

Comment: This is not a json response. Just use: `data = response.content` and parse with bs4